# How to create Regex that matches only 1 or 2

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I am currently using this regex as an expression on **input type = "number"**

```
var regex = /[1|2]+$/;
```

and based on test i am showing user error but it fails if user enter
21, 12, 11, 22, -21, -12, 11, 1.1,2.1 i just want to accept either 1 or 2 i have set **max and min** attribute but for mobile user can enter manually i need to handle it for both cases

Comment: You mean `/^[12]$/`

Comment: @anubhava it works fine it is not accepting negative or decimal number but it is accepting still 21,11,22,12 how to eliminate them ?

Comment: @MehulChachada `but it is accepting still 21,11,22,12` Are you shure you used the regex right? Try to use: `if(a.match(/^[12]$/) !== null){ /* OK */ }`

Comment: Just use `type="text" pattern="[12]"` and show an error if the entered value does not match.

Comment: @anubhava i have inserted code

Comment: @Bellian i have inserted code check it

Comment: You are using `/^[12]+$/` which is not same as `/^[12]$/` suggested above. If you want to allow negative/positive decimal number then use this regex: `/^[+-]?[12](?:\.\d+)?$/`

Comment: @anubhava yeah thanks i just now saw it silly mistake

Comment: Please, do not add answer in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `/^[12]$/` will be OK.

Comment: sorry, you needn't |

Comment: it works fine it is not accepting negative or decimal number but it is accepting still 21,11,22,12 i just want either single digit 1 or single digit 2 as input

Comment: @MehulChachada then you probably forgot to remove the `+` after the `[12]`. Copy the exact regex from this answer into your code.

Answer (score 3):

So you want to match only `1` or `2`?
Well, that's precisely what the `|` operator does:

```
1|2
```

If you want this to be a word:

```
\b(1|2)\b
```

Or a string/line:

```
^(1|2)$
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```js
const
  regex = /^[12]$/,
  tests = ['1', '2', '11', '21', '-1', '1|', '|'];
  
tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log(`Is '${test}' valid: ${regex.test(test)}`);
});
```